# Installing xml2 on CENTOS 6.9 x86_64 error

Tags: centos, installation, xml2

I get the following when I try

install.packages("xml2") 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"xml2"'

or
devtools::install_github("hadley/xml2")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"hadley/xml2"'

I have installed
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the libxml2?
If so you need to insatll first the EPEL repository and the libxml2 via yum.

Please follow this page:
https://www.google.at/amp/sharadchhetri.com/2014/05/24/how-to-install-libxml2-and-libxslt-packages-on-centos-6-5/amp/

Comment: Ok I guess you need to insatll RStudio first, please reference to: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-rstudio-server-on-centos-7

Comment: Or if you just want to use R, install EPEL first and then just yum install R